# Can't access Classes in default package

Tags: java, eclipse, package

I have a problem with the default package.
Basically my project structure consists of three main classes which extend one abstract class in a package called simulation.
Yesterday I did a name change in the project and now my three main classes are put automatically in the default package, so they can't be visible by the class inside the simulation package and vice versa.
For the following code

```
import simulation.*;

class SSQSim extends Simulation{

}
```

I get these errors
"This class must implement the inherited abstract method Simulation.stop(), but cannot override it since it is not visible from SSQSim. Either make the type abstract or make the inherited method visible"
"The type Simulation is not visible"

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**
The problem is that I don't have to use any other packages. It's basically homework and the rules for the submission are pretty strict: First, I have to submit the package "simulation" which contains the abstract class "Simulation" with some methods to implement with the help of the other classes. This part is fine.

Then, I have to create three classes which import the package "simulation" and extend its class "Simulation". They have specifically said not to put these classes in any package. At first, they all worked fine but after I renamed the project. These classes suddenly moved into the default package and now they give me these errors.

Comment: As a general rule, don't use the default package.

Comment: is `SSQSim` in the default package? (Is the sourcode you provided the complete file?)

Comment: @Matt Yes, I'm aware of this. The problem is that eclipse is putting all my classes in the default package automatically
@aioobe Yes, SSQSim is in the default package. Yes, the source code is fine and I was supposed to implement it to extend the Simulation abstract class. But I can't access it from the classes in default package.

Comment: @Micheal
Sorry maybe my post wasn't clear. My question is: How do I stop eclipse from putting my classes in the default package?

Comment: @Sre You have to specify package when creating class, or refactor it later. Alt+shift+T and choose move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you creating your classes? When you create a new class, Eclipse shows a `New Java Class` dialog. This dialog lets you choose which package to create your new class in:

[image]

Just click the `Browse` button and you'll be able to pick a package.

[image: enter image description here no i do not like image descriptions >:(]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I can't just change the name of the default package into a new one. The classes shouldn't be in any package, it's a requirement for submitting my exercise. 
I know there is a way not to put classes in any package at all because I did it before before and it worked fine.

Comment: @Sre: putting classes in the default package _is_ putting classes into no package.

Comment: @Sre: I just saw your edit that says _I have to submit the package "simulation" which contains the abstract class "Simulation"_. This means: **put your classes into a package called `simulation`.**

Answer (score 1):

Why you use the default package,From the java specs:

```
It is a compile time error to import a type from the unnamed package.
```

So you have to create a new package with a different name and add your classes or put them in the same package as your class and do the required imports.

Comment: He is not importing anything from the default package. He is importing from the `simulation` package.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that the signature of `Simulation.stop()` method mentions some class that is package-restricted (non-public) to the `simulation` package.

You solve it by either

1. Move `SSQSim` to the `simulation` package so it can access the same classes as `Simulation`, or
2. Make the classes required to extend the `Simulation` class package-public.

---

To move a class from one package to another in eclipse, you can simply drag the source-code file into the desired package, and eclipse will refactor the code accordingly.

---

(A side-note: As a rule of thumb, don't use the default package. The problem you ran into however, can occur even if you avoid the default package!)

Answer (score 0):

This is just a hint for now, as the source code for all the classes is not posted. The error message implies the presence of an abstract method in the parent class, that cannot be overriden due to loss in visibility in the child class. Usually, this is due to the use of the default access specifier ("friendly"), or the private access specifier (which is meaningless, especially if the method is declared as abstract). One will have to use the protected access modifier on the parent, to ensure that the method is now visible to all child classes irrespective of whether they are present in the same package or not.

In short, if the child cannot "see" the method that is being overriden, then the compiler issues a warning that informs about the inevitability to deduce whether the method defined in the parent or the child should used at runtime.

As far as Eclipse's behavior of creating classes in the default package is concerned, one can always ensure that a package is specified when creating a new class in the appropriate dialog (the new Java Class dialog, where a package field is present).

Comment: Where would he need to put the protected modifier?